# Foreach loop not listing all items

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through all the items inside an array and add it to a variable. However, i'm seeing only one item is displaying from the array after looping through.

The process below ithat i'm trying to use is to exclude pages from cache on WordPress.

Instead of seeing the three items when i echo the result i'm seeing only the last item which is /welcome/

I want all three items to be displayed to exclude all three pages instread of just one.

```
$pages = "/become-a-teacher/, /term-conditions/, /welcome/";

$delimiter = ' ';
$page_views = explode($delimiter, $pages);

foreach ($page_views as $page_view) {
   $uri = strtok( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?' );
   if ( in_array( $uri, [ $page_view ] )  ) { 
      cancel();
   }
}
 
echo "$page_view <br>";
```

Can anyone lead me towards how to fix this issue.

Comment: shouldn't the delimiter be `$delimiter = ', ';` ?

Comment: ^not even sure why OP just doesn't create an array to start with

Comment: `$page_view` will hold the last item that it got in the loop ....

Comment: you are only echoing `$page_view` once, after the foreach ... that means you are only printing the last page

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the echo inside the foreach:

```
foreach ($page_views as $page_view) {
   $uri = strtok( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?' );
   if ( in_array( $uri, [ $page_view ] )  ) { 
      cancel();
   }

   echo "$page_view <br>";
}
```

Comment: Cornel your example worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Tyrese glad I could help. You should mark my answer as correct and upvote it. That way others can benefit from correct answers to similar questions.